# Changing the top margin of one single page with typearea package

Tags: biblatex, margins, typearea

I have a bit of an exotic problem. I have a large document and want to extend the vertical margins of one specific page (publication list) in order to fit everything into one page. Extending the bottom is very easy with `\enlargethispage`. However, I just cannot extend the top margin. I use the `typearea` package (but no KOMA class) and `\areaset` for setting up the layout - I really don't want to change that (e.g. to `geometry`?) by any means possible...

Now the exotic part ist this: Many times I found as a suggestion (i.e. alternative to `geometry`) to use the `changepage` package and something like `\changepage{}{}{}{}{}{-3cm}{}{}{}` (6th parameter being the top margin). The particular page I want to be enlarged (publication list) is generated via biblatex. For some weird reason, the `\changepage` macro is not working here, i.e. it is apparently ignored. `\changepage` works however on a test document with `\areaset` as layout and a `\chapter*` as heading (similar to what biblatex does)... Here's the essential part of the code including all packages:

```
\documentclass[pdftex,openright,12pt,a4paper,twoside,notitlepage]{book}
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{typearea}
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[font={small,sf},labelfont=bf,margin=0pt]{caption}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[mathscr]{euscript}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=...,biblabel=brackets,defernumbers=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage[ocgcolorlinks,unicode]{hyperref}

\areaset[9mm]{15cm}{22cm} % <-- main layout
\addtolength{\topmargin}{15mm}
\setlength{\headheight}{14.5pt}

\defbibheading{publist}[1]{% <-- heading setup for biblatex environment
\chapter*{#1}%
\markboth{#1}{#1}%
\vspace*{-1.5cm}}% <-- additionally reduce spacing between "chapter" title and text

\defbibenvironment{publist} %  <-- environment setup for biblatex
{\list{}{\setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}}}
{\endlist}
{\item}

\begin{document}

... % lots of frontmatter stuff
\cleardoublepage

\begin{refsection}
\nocite{...} % <-- prepare citations for publication list
\phantomsection  % correct jump mark for hyperref
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of publications}
\changepage{}{}{}{}{}{-3cm}{}{}{} % <-- this is ignored!
\printbibliography[env=publist,heading=publist,title={...},sorting=none] % <-- bibliography with previously defined header/environment
\enlargethispage{4\baselineskip} % <-- this works fine
\vspace*{\stretch{1}}
\includegraphics{...} % <-- some logo at the page bottom
\end{refsection}
\clearpage
```

So, how can I shift only this particular page with the "special" bibliography up without screwing up everything?

Comment: Would be easier to help if you gave us compilable code we can use to reproduce.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you can use something like that

```
\usepackage{typearea}
\AfterSettingArea{\setlength{\headheight}{14.5pt}}
\areaset[9mm]{15cm}{22cm} % <-- main layout
\addtolength{\topmargin}{15mm}% (297-220):3x2-36.3=15
...
\cleardoublepage
\storeareas\StandardArea% <- store the main layout
\areaset[9mm]{15cm}{24cm}% <- change the layout
\addtolength{\topmargin}{1.7mm}% (297-240):3x2-36.3=1.7
...
\clearpage
\StandardArea% <- restore main layout
```

[image]
[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[pdftex,openright,12pt,a4paper,twoside,notitlepage]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}
\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}% example bib file

\defbibheading{publist}[1]{% <-- heading setup for biblatex environment
\chapter*{#1}%
\markboth{#1}{#1}%
\vspace*{-1.5cm}}% <-- additionally reduce spacing between "chapter" title and text

\defbibenvironment{publist} %  <-- environment setup for biblatex
{\list{}{\setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}}}
{\endlist}
{\item}

\usepackage{typearea}
\AfterSettingArea{\setlength{\headheight}{14.5pt}}
\areaset[9mm]{15cm}{22cm} % <-- main layout
\addtolength{\topmargin}{15mm}% (297-220):3x2-36.3=15


\usepackage{showframe}% to show the pagelayout
\usepackage{mwe}% dummy text and example image

\usepackage[ocgcolorlinks,unicode]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument

\cleardoublepage
\storeareas\StandardArea% <- store the main layout
\areaset[9mm]{15cm}{24cm}% <- change the layout
\addtolength{\topmargin}{1.7mm}% (297-240):3x2-36.3=1.7
\begin{refsection}
\nocite{westfahl:space}% only example
\phantomsection  % correct jump mark for hyperref
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of publications}
\printbibliography[env=publist,heading=publist,title={...},sorting=none] % <-- bibliography with previously defined header/environment
\enlargethispage{2\baselineskip} % <-- this works fine
\vspace*{\stretch{1}}
\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image} % <-- some logo at the page bottom
\end{refsection}

\clearpage
\StandardArea% <- restore main layout
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thanks a lot! I didn't know you could use \areaset outside the preamble (also the tricks to store and restore the layout). However, it produces a typearea warning, saying that it's a "dirty hack" and shouldn't be used by anyone ;)... I'm fine with that, since anything else seems ok - but is there also a "clean" way?